# Do I need an airport transit visa for Dublin, Ireland en route to the UK?

Tags: visas, transit, ireland, haitian-citizens

I am Haitian, and traveling with a Haitian passport. I have to go to London with a work permit (tier 2 visa) on the 29th of July but I have 2 hour transit in Dublin.

Do I need a transit visa? Can I get it at the airport?

I also have a valid US visa.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20visas) only citizens of the following countries require a transit visa:

> - Afghanistan
> - Albania
> - Cuba
> - Democratic Republic of the Congo
> - Eritrea
> - Ethiopia
> - Ghana
> - Iran
> - Iraq
> - Lebanon
> - Moldova
> - Nigeria
> - Somalia
> - Sri Lanka
> - Zimbabwe

All others (including you) should be able to transit without one.  Same can be confirmed on [Timatic used by the airlines](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=HT&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&EM=HT&TR=IE&VT=00&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C)

Comment: One thing that should be mentioned is that, due to the [unusual design of Dublin Airport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/46326/3221), you _will_ pass through a passport control when transiting, even if you do not claim baggage. You should not be alarmed by this, as that particular control leads directly from the arrivals area to the departures area. Further, it does not affect whether you need a transit visa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a visa for Ireland. Since the UK and Ireland have a Common Travel Area, you have to pass border control to enter Ireland before you can get to your flight from Ireland to the UK.

There is an exception that you can enter Ireland with a UK visa if you have already been admitted to the UK with a UK passport stamp that is still unexpired, but you can't use that exception until you get the UK passport stamp by entering the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Dublin Airport has very bad transit facilities. Even if you have a transit visa or don't need one, you cannot:

- stay overnight,
- transfer from one terminal to another, or
- collect your bags and check them in to your onward flight.

Source: http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit