# Indian National Travelling from USA to India via Dublin

Tags: international-travel, indian-citizens, dublin

I am flying from Chicago, USA to Hyderabad, India on June 4th.
My initial flight is AA which goes to Dublin (reaches around 740AM June 5)
My connection is Etihad from the same airport (leaves around 905AM June 5)

In this scenario
Will I need to apply for any kind of visa upfront?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34300/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa-for-dublin-ireland-with-haiti-passport)?

Comment: Not if you are staying airside.

Comment: @edocetirwi Dublin Airport does not have airside transit. All transit passengers pass through passport control (but not customs).

Answer (score 3):

According to this site - http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20Visas India is not in the list of countries which require transit visa. So you would not need one to transit through Dublin.

> Check if you need a transit visa 
>  Nationals of the states or territorial entities listed below are subject to an Irish transit visa requirement.
>   **Afghanistan, Ethiopia, Moldova, Albania, Ghana, Nigeria, Cuba, Iran, Somalia, Democratic Republic of Congo, Iraq, Sri Lanka, Eritrea, Lebanon, Zimbabwe**

Since visa rules keeps changing from time to time better check them before making any plans.

Answer (score -1):

You only need transit visas if you will be passing through immigration, sometimes you have to, such as when you need to change airports. You have minimal layover time at Dublin airport and I think you are not even changing terminal, in that case no need for any kind of visa.

Also, a word of advise, it seems a code-share flight, so look out when you are searching for your gate at the airport, means it's totally possible that you are assuming it's an AA flight but Etihad is carrying you or vice versa, in this case they will be showing flight numbers of both airlines, both will be different, just keep a good eye on them!

Comment: This is not completely correct, some countries (eg the UK) require people of certain nationalities to hold a visa even for direct airside transit - see many questions here for details