# I am a resident of a non-Schengen country flying to the US via Dublin and Zurich. Do I need a Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, zurich, thai-citizens

I know there is a popular question already answered - [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) - but I am still unclear on some of the rules applying to my specific case, due to the fact that the UK is a 'sort of in the Schengen area but not so' and also some other exceptions arising from the US visa.

I am a Thai passport holder with a Work Permit (Tier 2) in the UK and a B1/B2 visa to the US. I'm flying to the US via Dublin outgoing, then via Zurich and Dublin return. The aforementioned question implies that I'll need a visa for the intra-Schengen transfer on my return, but could I cut the ZUR-DUB leg of the journey and book a ZUR-LHR flight in the Zurich transfer area, or would this be outside the passport check area?

Would I need to carry on all luggage due to the baggage carousel being outside the border control stations?

Comment: Dublin is not in the Schengen area, period. There is no intra-Schengen flight in a LHR-ZHR-DUB-somewhere to the US itinerary. But if you need to collect your luggage in Zurich, you might need to clear immigration, even on if you were not transiting in Dublin.

Comment: Dublin Airport has some unique transit issues, which I've discussed at [Ireland Transit Visa when flying from IND - Abu Dhabi - Dublin - US](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/ireland-transit-visa-when-flying-from-ind-abu-dhabi-dublin-us). In short, you do not need a transit visa, and you do not need to pick up your bags, but you will go through passport control.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a better answer calling your airline. Does the flight UK > Dublin > US have simply a scale in Dublin or do you have to land there? Normally if it's just transfer you don't have to pick up your luggage. But if you do, then you have to enter the border control and therefore you need the visa. Just ask them this, they are the ones who will be able to tell you.

Comment: I understood the question to be about the Zurich end of the trip…