# Do i need Transit Visa for the Republic of Ireland?

Tags: visas, transit, ireland

I am travelling from Boston to Rome. I have Indian Passport and have a schengen visa. My flight is from Boston - Dublin with 7 hour layover and Dublin - Rome.

I just want to find out if i need to apply for a transit visa.

Comment: As described in [Ireland Transit Visa when flying from IND - Abu Dhabi - Dublin - US](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/ireland-transit-visa-when-flying-from-ind-abu-dhabi-dublin-us), you do not need a transit visa, but there is a specific route you must follow through Dublin Airport.

Answer (score 4):

Does an Indian national (Chinese national, Nigerian national, Albanian national, etc etc) need a transit visa for the Republic of Ireland?

Looking at the screen shot (generated on 5 Feb 2016), one observes the nationalities that require a transit visa...

[image: https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/]

Source: [Visas for Ireland](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/)

Note: Schengen visas do not work in the Republic.

Note: The person's flight origin and destination do not matter as long as both are outside the Common Travel Area.

Comment: If you feel keen, it looks like we could probably use a canonical Ireland transit visa question. I was sure we had a duplicate for this one, but it turns out none of them were general enough :/

Comment: @Gagravarr I spent some time combing the archives looking for the canonical and came up empty; it was surprising.  I will try to canonicalize the question and we can see how far we get.

Comment: @Gagravarr can you check it now?

Comment: It's a shame there's no handy wizard like for the UK, but the page you linked to actually looks quite short and easy to understand!