# Do I need a Transit visa to fly Delhi-Zurich-Dublin-St. Johns (Canada)?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I have journey to make from Delhi to Canada on a Canadian Student visa. I am an Indian Passport holder. My itinerary is Delhi to Zurich to Dublin to St. John's (Canada).

As far as I know Zurich (Switzerland) is a schengen country and Dublin (Ireland) is a non-schengen country.

My query is do I need a transit visa for the 8 hours (at Zurich) and 2 hours (at Dublin) layover periods in these countries?

Thanks

Comment: @Jan It also asks about Ireland, so not entirely a duplicate

Comment: @Crazydre The Ireland part of the question is addressed [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/ireland-transit-visa-when-flying-from-ind-abu-dhabi-dublin-us).

Comment: I *thought* (but apparantly that was only a flag) that there had been a dupe vote on the Ireland part of the question. If that had been the case, both links would have shown up. But apparantly, there hadn’t been, I was the first actual close vote and thus the Ireland question is not showing up now. Oh damn.

Comment: OP's travel plans are now sorted out after private convos with me, just so everyone knows. OP ended up booking Delhi-Mumbai-London-St Johns. No immigration controls (baggage through-checked) although OP could clear UK immigration based on their Canadian visa

Answer (score 1):

You do not Need a visa for either country. Like you wrote Switzerland is the only Schengen country, and Ireland is the only CTA country.

At Dublin, even when using the transit corridor, you will be checked by immigration, but you'll just present the passport and onward Boarding pass