# Transit in Dublin on two tickets US to Manila via DUB and IST

Tags: transit, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, dublin, dub

I am very confused and think I might have made a mistake. My partner is a Filipino passport holder leaving the US to return home to Manila - but he must exit via Orlando, FL (MCO).

Two tickets were booked:

- Aer Lingus MCO-DUB, 6 hour layover.
- Turkish Air DUB-IST-MNL on one ticket.

Does he have to fully clear immigration and check in with Turkish Airlines landside and thus need a visa - ie enter Ireland? What if he has no luggage?

I found mixed info on websites - including he does have to fully clear immigration to get bags (if he checks them in) but immigration would allow it if he shows an onward ticket.

What if I am accompanying him (US passport holder)?

I don't quite understand the self-connecting restrictions but worry that he needs a visa and it is too late (travel Jan 6).

Comment: Are you quite certain that he must exit via a specific airport? This would be extremely unusual, especially since the US does not have immigration exit controls. Exactly what does the visa annotation say, verbatim?

Answer (score 1):

[Timatic tells me](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PH&NV=Philippines&DC=PH&DV=Philippines&TC=IE&TV=Ireland&h=d336938fa9bf1b0e52aa25f89437d3df4bac68) that a transit through Ireland on separate tickets by a person holding a passport from the Philippines requires a transit visa. The airline will check Timatic at check-in and may deny boarding if Timatic tells the check-in agent that the passenger does not have required documents or may be refused entry.

Note that Dublin airport is the only airport in the EU [without an airside transit area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/46326/3221). Everyone transiting through DUB has to go through a passport control regardless of whether they are transiting or entering Ireland. There is, however, a specific passport control used (almost) exclusively by transiting passengers, so officers at that control will be expecting transits and may be more lenient, given that he is transiting to his home country.

He is likely to be denied boarding at MCO if he attempts to fly on these tickets. At this point your best bet is to change his bookings.

Comment: If it was in a single booking, OP could transit visa-free at terminal 2, as there is transit passport control there, similar to Oslo airport

Comment: @Coke [Yes, there is.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/46326/3221) Unfortunately he is not on a single booking.

Comment: follow up:  Are Lingus now states (res #) that if partner (Filipino) has hand carry only, then CAN pass through T2 to T1 airside transit (which they do have) despite being two separate tickets.  Two different agents confidently proclaimed this.  However, emails to airport and even govt help links keep referring back to airline - given the inconsistent responses form Aer Lingus and nothing in writing, not going to push luck.

Comment: @user70880 There's one passport control at DUB that's used exclusively for transiting passengers. You might get Aer Lingus to board him, but as a matter of law the transit is not allowed and he might be denied at the passport control and sent back to the US.

Comment: @Michael Hampton and Coke- I really appreciate your insight.  We are now booked on Norwegian Air: MCO-LGW-SIN but on one ticket so only change of flights on Norwegian in LGW. Bags thru to SIN.  Norwegian agent said no transit visa needed.  We plan to collect bags in SIN and we will take SQ to MNL (should be no problem clearing in SIN to get bags).  So is THAT correct?: Can connect in LGW because not leaving terminal and on same ticket? Seems that the Gov. website says we are ok also, but given the ticket is non-refundable and the trouble thus far, I would feel better with your thoughts. thx

Comment: If you are doing an Landside transit in the UK, and you have a (just expired) US Visa, then you do NOT need a traveller-in-transit visa. You must be on the next reasonable flight out of the UK.

be travelling to (or on part of a reasonable journey to) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the **USA** and have a valid visa for that country

Source: 

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/somewhere_else/yes


 From: 
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa