# Do I need a Transit visa at Dublin Airport if my transit is through the same terminal of the airport?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dub

I hold a Canadian visa on an Indian passport.

From India I will be arriving at Dublin on Ethiopian Airlines and after a 3 hrs 40 mins layover will catch WestJet Airlines to Canada from the same terminal at which I will have arrived at Dublin Airport. According to the airlines I will have to collect and recheck the baggage at Dublin Airport.

Do I need a Transit visa?

Comment: You will not need a transit visa for your layover at DUB; a relevant link is posted in the accepted answer to *[Do I need an airport transit visa for Dublin, Ireland?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34300)*

Comment: I checked the link. I have also asked Dublin Airport infodesk through email. But they are saying as I will have to collect the bag and recheck it, I will have to cross into their boarder and clear customs. So they are suggesting that I will need a transit visa. So what's the point of waiving the transit visa requirement of Indian citizens as per the their Naturalization and Immigration Website?

Comment: @Aakash, hey, did you end up getting the transit visa? Or did it work out without one?

Answer (score 7):

Collecting bagage is normally after immigration control, but before customs. Looking at [the INIS site](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit) only if you stay airside you do not need a visa. Collecting bagage implies you have to go through immigration so you would need a short stay visa.

Text from the INIS site:

> When you arrive in Ireland, you will remain 'airside' of the border while you wait for your connecting flight.
> You must apply for a short stay Visit Visa if you want to pass through border control, eg if you are transiting overnight and want to stay in a hotel.
> If you do not have a short stay Visit Visa, you will not be allowed to pass through border control.

I find it odd that you wil have to claim your bagage at Dublin, must be a reason for that. This may be true if you booked this journey as two separate journeys. In that cases they can not check you through.

Comment: What in that case defines "transfer" mentioned in [here](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20Visas)? If you do not pass the border control you do not need a visa anyway, neither short stay nor transfer. So what's the airport-related use case for these "transfer" visas?

Comment: I awarded bounty here because, even though the controversy I see about transit Irish visa is still unresolved, this answer makes it most clear that you need a Short Stay one if you want to pass the border control.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are all good, I am adding my own to add another caveat worth keeping in mind.

You mention that the airlines are requiring you to collect and recheck your baggage - this indicates that most probably you are travelling on a multiple ticket itinerary.

Both Paul Palmpje's and JonathanReez's answers cover the fact that you need a transit visa in order to collect the luggage, as the luggage collection point is after immigration control.

*A more pressing issue is that because you are not booked on a through-itinerary, the airline carrying you to Ireland will almost certainly not board you due to a lack of a visa and a lack of an ongoing-travel itinerary with them.  They will treat you as if Ireland is your final destination, because to them it is.*

Comment: What if you do not have any checked-in baggage? That it, if you have only the 8kg-max cabin bag..

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would be exempted thanks to your Canadian visa, however you mention that:

> According to the airlines I will have to collect and recheck the baggage at Dublin Airport.

This means you will indeed need a transit visa as the luggage collection takes place after passport control.

Answer (score 2):

My experience. Indian citizen with a U.S. visa.

Flying through Chicago to Dublin and connection from Dublin to Europe (within two hours in afternoon) - transit visa not required.

Flying back from Europe to Dublin. Connecting flight to Chicago is after 20 hrs. Arrived in Dublin airport at 4 PM. Cannot stay on the airport in the night as the airport is closed. Have to pass through immigration. Transit visa is required but do not have it. So, immigration office scolds and stamps an entry permit and warns not to repeat the case. Once the passport is stamped, left the airport, stayed at a hotel in the city centre, returned back to airport, passed through immigration and boarded the flight.

Had asked both the airline (Aer Lingus) and the Irish Consultate in Chicago before boarding, if I will need a transit visa on return. But no clear response from both of them.

Summary - You need a transit visa to travel through Dublin if you land in Dublin on Day 1 evening and your connecting flight is on Day 2 morning. You cannot stay at the airport (not even airside). The airline doesn't stop you from boarding the flight to Dublin if you don't have a transit visa, but once in Dublin you need to have it.

Comment: The airline may stop you from boarding the flight to Dublin, although in your case they did not.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IE&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   Not applicable to nationals of Afghanistan, Albania, Congo
>      (Dem. Rep.), Cuba, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Georgia, Ghana, Iran,
>      Iraq, Lebanon, Moldova (Rep.), Nigeria, Somalia, Sri Lanka,
>      Ukraine and Zimbabwe.

So far it looks good, but the defintion of TWOV is:

> Passing through an international
>   transit area of the airport in order to board a connecting (or
>   to proceed by the same) flight, **without entering the country
>   (i.e. clearing immigration)**.

So unfortunately, you **do** need a transit visa

Comment: Note that Timatic no longer says 24 hours; now it is you must stay in terminal 2 and transit between 04:00 and 16:00 of the same calendar day.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Indeed, and the border control will confirm the same (bmu@justice.ie)